# How to use select tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select

I was trying to implement dropdown menus on my website. I am using a similar code to this.

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option> 
</select>
<button>Try it</button>
```

I don't know how to findout what has been selected, and read it in javascript.

Comment: show what have you tired and what error you are getting?

Comment: It would have taken much lesser time if you'd have just searched it instead of framing a new ques..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want, the value or the text correspondent to the value.

If you want the actual value:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("your-dropdown-id");
var dropdownValue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

If you want the text, just change the property you are looking for:

```
var dropdownText = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
```